# Get a file under WEB-INF using Spring

Tags: spring, file, javabeans

I am trying to get a File under my WEB-INF/classes folder using Spring.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="path.to.MyBean" >
    <property name="myFile">
        <value>file:WEB-INF/classes/myFile.foo</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, when I print out the myFile's File Path from inside MyBean it is:

```
c:\\apache\bin\WEB-INF\classes\myFile.foo
```

So it is not using the relative deployment path.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 <value>classpath:WEB-INF/classes/myFile.foo</value>
```

or

```
 <value>classpath:myFile.foo</value>
```

Comment: <value>classpath:myFile.foo</value> worked like a charm!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<property name="myFile" value="/myFile.foo"/>
```

**and** read it using:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(myFile);
```

`myFile` is a `String`.

Another approach is to store the file in the same directory as the package of `MyBean` (`/WEB-INF/classes/path/to/myFile.foo`) and read it in the following way:

```
<property name="myFile" value="myFile.foo"/>
```

Notice there is no leading `/` - the path is relative to the current class (`getClass()` invocation).